# Hide columns in Excel export of SSRS Report

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export, ssrs-2012

I'd like to have several non-adjacent columns in an SSRS report, that when exported to Excel, by default are hidden in the worksheet. If the user would like to see them they could choose to unhide them from within Excel. I've tried playing with the visibility but when they are hidden, its like they never existed once I export to Excel. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,
Sean

Comment: Add VBA to your workbook which hides the columns when it is opened.

Comment: @Variatus how do you add VBA to a sheet that has just been created by SSRS?

Comment: @Harry, that was going to be my same question. Also I believe our company email policy would block such a worksheet as it seems like a security vulnerability.

Comment: You add the code at the point where the sheet is opened in Excel.

Comment: @Variatus I think you misunderstood the question. The open event would be the place to put any such code. What Harry and I were asking is how that code could be placed since the excel file is being generated by SSRS. You'd need to manually place the code. In my case, the report generation, export, and emailing is an automated process.

Comment: Seen from my point of view I would then have to ask if you have access to the point where the report is opened. I am thinking of a macro installed on that machine which would identify the report for what it is and take action in the way you want, ignoring all other documents opened there.